# How do I pass .xml from jQuery to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm using `jQuery.ajax()` to submit a form on my website. I get an .xml response and I want to send it to a .php file. I've tried using another `jQuery.ajax()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myURL',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function(xml)
        {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'saveData.php',
            data: {
              xml: $(xml),
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('#output').html(data);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

but I faced `"Illegal invocation"` error. So I added `processData: false` to my inner AJAX function. Now I get another error: `Undefined index: xml in...` Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $xml = $_POST['xml'];
?>
```

How to manage this issue?

Comment: You will need to parse the `XML` content and convert it to object that jquery/php can accept

Comment: why do you need to send a jquery object: `xml: $(xml),`? Try stripping the jquery object notation. `xml: xml,`.

Comment: @Jai Tried it and still getting this error.

Comment: $(xml)  is returning null, so in xml: $(xml) you're sending a null value in the variable  $_POST['xml'].

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi How can you tell if it's returning null?

Comment: It's because of your second error:
Undefined index: xml. The variable $_POST["xml"] don't exist in the page called.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: Check what you're sending before sending.
You can use alerts to debug vars in javascript and var_dumps to debug vars in php.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is specify in the first `$.ajax` call that you are going to receive an XML using `dataType` :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myURL',
    dataType: 'xml,
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(xml) (...)
```

But I have a question.
Why using an ajax into an other ajax call ?
If both are made to the same server, it dont seems legit.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. 'myURL' is an external server.

Comment: Ok if its an external server. Did you try to mix my answer with @Jai comment about using `xml : xml` instead of `xml : $(xml)` in the second $.ajax ?

Comment: Yes, I did and it also didn't help.

Comment: You said you're using an external server. If you're using two diferent servers, maybe you will have to deal with XSS. There's an answer in Stackoverflow suggesting to use JSONP to overcome the issues of cross site Scripting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to debug. Maybe if you change xml: $(xml) for xml: **$(xml).val()** you get what you wanted.

Uncoment the line alert($(xml).val()) and you will see what is the content of $(xml).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {

    $('#form').submit(function(e) 
    {
          e.preventDefault();

         // alert($(xml).val()); 


          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testpost.php',
                data: {
                  xml: $("#xml").val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $('#output').html(data);
                }
          });

    });

  })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form" method="POST">
<textarea name="xml" id="xml"><myxml>this is a test</myxml></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="output">Nothing executed till now</div>

</body>
</html>
```

testpost.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST["xml"]);
```